# Turning Input into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Write a Python program which accepts a sequence of comma-separated numbers from user and generate a list and a tuple with those numbers.

```
values = input("Input some comma separated numbers : ")

list = values.split(",")

tuple = tuple(list)
print('List : ',list)


print('Tuple : ',tuple)
```

This does work but is there any other easier way?

Comment: How much easier do you want that to get?  It's pretty straight forward.  The only comment I'd make is that you shouldn't use `list` and `tuple` in python code as variables because then you can no longer make a list or a tuple with them

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more efficient way to do this, check out this question:
[Most efficient way to split strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602856/most-efficient-way-to-split-strings-in-python)

If you're looking for a clearer or more concise way, this is actually quite simple. I would avoid using "tuple" and "list" as variable names however, it is bad practice to name variables as their type.

Comment: The linked question isn't really relevant; it's about splitting when you have multiple delimiters (so a single `str.split` call doesn't work), so you're choosing between regexes and doing one `str.split` followed by another split of one or more of the resulting strings. When it's "I want to split on a single fixed delimiter", the answer is `str.split`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code that you have written is pretty concise but you could remove few more line by using the below code:

```
values = input("Enter some numbers:\n").split(",")
print(values) #This is the list
print(tuple(values)) #This is the tuple
```